# Spike in frequency domain in a dataset recorded using electromagnetic flow meter

Tags: fluid-mechanics, sensors, water-resources, signal-processing

I am trying to measure the water velocity of a stream along a channel using an electromagnetic flow meter at a specific location and depth. When I converted the data into frequency domain as power spectral density (PSD), there was a spike at the frequency of 25 Hz.

Out of curiosity, I tried to make a recording using a bucket of still water, and similarly there was a spike at 25 Hz too, although at a lower magnitude (please see the plot below).

Also, the PSD starts quite highly from the lowest frequency, which slowly decreases. I was kind of expecting a simple flat plot with some noise, but maybe I was wrong.

In the plot below, the red line is the recorded data from the water stream (`Ch2 (Original)`), while the green one is the recorded data from the still water (`Noise`).
[image: PSD plot]

My questions are:

1. Are the spike and the general decreasing trend expected? If not, what might cause them? I suspected the old uncalibrated device might introduce noise in the form of a spike, but I am not sure.
2. I would like to get the "peaks" information to find the water vortex frequencies, but this will definitely include that spike frequency. How do I remove that spike such that I can get the actual peaks? I tried to use notch filter but depending on the parameters, it either didn't eliminate the spike enough, or too much...it was quite difficult to configure.

Any suggestion and feedback is welcome. Thank you so much!

**UPDATE**

The sampling frequency is 100 Hz.

This is the specification document to the flow meter: [Kenek VM2201・VMT2-200-04P](https://www.kenek-co.com/english/pdf/VM2201%E3%83%BBVMT2-200-04P.pdf)

This is some information about the data logger: [Kenek AD1016](https://web.archive.org/web/20090106002701/http://www.kenek-co.com/adusb.html)

The time-domain plots are added below. They are all from the same data, only one plot is zoomed in from the previous one. I think the labels on the x axis is wrong. They are just numbers in here.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: what is the powerline frequency in your location?

Comment: @jsotola As in the electric current frequency? Data was taken in east Japan, so it seems to be [50Hz](https://www.tepco.co.jp/en/corpinfo/ir/kojin/supply/transformation-e.html#:~:text=Power%20Interchange%20between%20East%20and,interchanging%20electric%20power%20between%20areas.).

Comment: Since the peak is quite pronounced, you can double check if it is correct by plotting the raw time-value data and see if a sine wave of 25 Hz is "visible" upon magnifying the plot. Also, what is the sampling frequency? Also, does this device output **frequency modulated** signal? If so, the actual measurement is the deviation of the measured frequency from a predefined frequency (probably 25 Hz).

Comment: The device could also be **amplitude modulated**. See these web search results : [1](https://www.omega.com/en-us/resources/magmeter#section1), [Wikipedia reference](https://cdn.krohne.com/dlc/BR_EMF_en_2011.pdf#page=151). Please share the details of the meter with us (e.g. a datasheet)

Comment: @AJN I added the information in the main post. As you wrote, the time-series data indeed seem to show the sine wave. (I need to fix the x axis label by the way.) I also added the link to the device's spec guide. Unfortunately that's the only thing I found. How do I know if it outputs frequency or amplitude modulated signals?

Comment: "*How do I know if it outputs frequency or amplitude modulated signals*". Those were only guesses from my side. How are you *setting* the sampling frequency as 100Hz? How are you reading the data? Using their own proprietary software or directly reading from the RS-232 port? How are you *setting* the RS232 communication parameters?

Comment: does seems like could be an artifact of the data acquisition process? If the ADC is a sigma delta type (very common), you can get funky modulation effects which then can alias down into lower frequencies. The decreasing PSD (looks like 40 db/decade in amplitude) might just be a 2nd order filter or pair of integrators (no idea why)

Comment: Can you alter the sampling rate? That would give helpful clues

Comment: Also AFAIK, measuring devices that use a modulated excitation, tend to put the modulation at least beyond the powerline frequency

Comment: Sorry for the delay in reply. I am not sure how to set the frequency to be honest, as I just used the existing settings. There is a "measuring range" knob which was set to 100 cm/s, but I am not sure if it sets the sampling frequency. Regarding the data reading, the X and Y output are connected to a data logger device using RS232 on both ends, then the logger is connected to a PC using USB cable. There is a piece of software on the PC which records and display the data, I am guessing it is proprietary.

Comment: I found some information about the data logger. However, it's in Japanese and is old (dated 2009 on the Wayback Machine). The software is also part of the data logging system.

Comment: I am curious about the (de)modulation process. I thought the data logging device will do it for me, but do I need to do something to get the actual data? Perhaps the sampling rate can also be adjusted from the software, but practically this is quite hard to do as I will have to repeat the experiments.